# convert numberic / mathematic conversion in Perl

Tags: perl

I have some **LaTeX** input like this:

`\num{123} \\
\num{1234} \\
\num{12345} \\
\num{0.123} \\
\num{0.1234} \\
\num{.12345} \\
\num{3.45d-4} \\
\num{-e10}\\
\num{0.12345(9)}\\
\num{1e2}\\
\num{e-3}\\
\num{e4}\\
\num{1.23e4}`

This is the expected Output:

`123 \\
1234 \\
12\,345 \\
0.123 \\
0.1234 \\
0.123\,45 \\
$3.45 \times 10^{-4}$ \\
$-10^{10}$ \\
0.123\,45(9) \\
$1 \times 10^{2}$ \\
$10^{-3}$ \\
$10^{4}$ \\
$1.23 \times 10^{4}$`

I can able to do first four of patterns we do in norm regex however I can't do rest of the things in Perl.

Already I wrote this question in SO site. But unfortunately I didn't get matched answers (question deleted by me). Could some help me on this one.

Perl script only preferable rather than using LaTeX packages.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, there's two problem here: Extracting the numerical expression, and parsing it. `s/\\num\{\K([^{}]*)(?=\})/ f($1) /eg` might suffice for the former. The latter could be done with a number of search and replaces. (Commas left of the `.`. Commas right of it. Conversion of magnitude.)

Comment: @ikegami: Do you have any solution on this one?

Answer (score 1):

I would divide the problem in two: 1) get the numeric string; 2) formatting it according to your needs.

For the formatting part, you could take a look to some modules, like Number::Format; it doesn't maybe do everything you need, but it is, in my opinion, better than parsing the string yourself from scratch. You may further modify it later.

Matching the numeric string shouldn't be too difficult; maybe something like /\\num\{([^}]+)\}/ could do the trick. From your example, it seems almost all the strings may be submitted to Number::Format as they are.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your answer.. Pls explain in detail to understand

Comment: Sorry, it seems I misunderstood your requirements; Number::Format it's not so useful as I thought.

For the rest, I suggested (as ikegami) to first get the numeric part:

    open HIN, '<', 'numbers.tex';
    my $num;
    while (<HIN>) {
        ($num) = ($_ =~ /\\num\{([^}]+)\}/);
        format_number($num);
    }

then process it (let's start with the exponential notation):

   sub format_number {
       my $n = shift;
       my ($base, $exp) = split /e/i, $n;
       ...
   }

and so on.